# Remove invalid XML characters from XmlElement function

Tags: oracle

I have a table (called `SMARTDATA`) that stores long notes by splitting them into 512-character lines:

```
ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(18)    
LINE  NOT NULL NUMBER(38) 
TEXT           VARCHAR2(512)
```

The workflow allow users to paste HTML text into the application's control that eventually populates the `SMARTDATA` table.

For reporting purposes, the notes are serialized into a single row:

```
SELECT  id, 
        RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,text,'').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY LINE).GetClobVal(),',') NOTES
FROM    smartdata
GROUP BY id
```

Unfortunately, some of the characters that are entered (e.g. [CANCEL; U+0018](https://unicode-table.com/en/0018/)) lead the `XmlElement()` function to generate an error: `ORA-64451: Conversion of special character to escaped character failed.`

While I can certainly replace the individual characters with a zero-length string, this is a brittle solution:

```
SELECT  id,
        RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,  replace(text,UNISTR('\0018'), ''), '').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY LINE).GetClobVal(),',') NOTES
FROM    smartdata
GROUP BY id
```

Is there a more-effective way to remove the offending characters from the `text` field, rather than having to list them individually?

** edit **

Test data:

```
WITH 

data as ( select 'A           A' text from dual )
SELECT dump(text, 1010) FROM dual

Typ=96 Len=14 CharacterSet=WE8ISO8859P1: 65,32,32,32,24,32,32,32,32,32,32,160,32,65
```

It would appear that code point 24 doesn't exist in [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), hence the error.